# HMAC using Linux Kernel Crypto APIs not the same as the one by OpenSSL command

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, openssl, hmac

I tried code(Using Linux Kernel Crypto APIs) for calculating HMAC-SHA512 on a file.
Surprisingly, HMAC calculated from the kernel code and from OpenSSL commands are different.

OpenSSL commands are:

```
openssl rand -base64 16
plakOhrXlfnBENPVBo91kg==
openssl dgst -sha512 -mac hmac -macopt key:plakOhrXlfnBENPVBo91kg== ../hello6.ko  
HMAC-SHA512(../hello6.ko)=   9605f40851630f5b7a18fa30c7e5d6f1e77afb011d319efa515556d12ba6930f459825b3695a0d0d910a714724c0d99b36ccea5c878962b32a8de65dcbcc247d
```

HMAC-SHA512 from the kernel code is:

```
84306723b713379aa666fe9aa75af3192a9707d19136c25dd2286c5f6d86dfd8f76ceaa0ce147b53c0e9f7bfab485f38f5139c687c34c840db7f7fa9438bf8b0d8df8e770088ffffc8de8e770088ffffc3f027a0ffffffff672c00000088fffff0de8e770088ffff1900000000000080672c000000000000e8de8e770088ffff
```

How come these HMACs are different for the same content? Any pointers to get rid of this issue is very helpful.

Base64 encoded key is generated by below command and stored in a file:

```
openssl rand -base64 -out $Module_name.sha512key 16
```

HMAC is generated on a file and stored in a file.
    openssl dgst -sha512 -mac hmac -macopt key:$HMAC_KEY $HMAC_PATH/$Module_name> temp.txt

Key and File content are read by below code:

```
    static char hmac[HMAC_SHA512_SIZE];
    const char *kofilename = "/home/sri/Documents/Hello/hello6.ko";
    const char *hmackey_file = "/home/sri/Documents/Hello/hello6.ko.sha512key"; 
    const char *hmac_file = "/home/sri/Documents/Hello/hello6.ko.sha512"; 

    unsigned char *data = NULL;
    int readkostatus;
    int readkeystatus;
    int readhmacstatus;

    unsigned char *hmackey = NULL;
    unsigned char *stored_hmac = NULL; 

    readkeystatus = read_file(hmackey_file, &hmackey); 

    if(readkeystatus < 0)
        goto readkeyerr;

    printk(KERN_INFO "HMAC Key is :%s", hmackey);

    readkostatus = read_kofile(kofilename, &data);

    if(readkostatus < 0)
        goto readkoerr;

    printk(KERN_INFO "File data size is :%ld", strlen(data)); 
    printk(KERN_INFO "File data is :%s", data);

    hmac_sha512(hmackey, data, hmac, sizeof(hmac)); 
    printk(KERN_INFO "FINAL HMAC:%s", hmac);

    readhmacstatus = read_file(hmac_file, &stored_hmac); 

    if(readhmacstatus < 0)
    goto readhmacerr;

    printk(KERN_INFO "Stored HMAC:%s", stored_hmac);

    if(!memcmp(stored_hmac, hmac, HMAC_SHA512_SIZE))    
    printk(KERN_INFO "HMACs match");
    else
        printk(KERN_INFO "HMACs do not match"); 

    vfree(stored_hmac); 
    vfree(data); 
    vfree(hmackey); 

    return 0;

   readkeyerr:
   {
       printk(KERN_INFO "hmac key read error:%d", readkeystatus);    
       return readkeystatus;
   }

   readkoerr:
   {
       printk(KERN_INFO "ko read error:%d", readkostatus);        
       return readkostatus;
   }

   readhmacerr:
   {
       printk(KERN_INFO "hmac read error:%d", readhmacstatus);
       return readhmacstatus;
   }
```

Code for reading the files is given below:

```
    int read_file(const char *filename, unsigned char **data)
    {
        struct file* filp = NULL; 
        long filesize;  
        int ret = 0;


        mm_segment_t old_fs = get_fs();
        set_fs(get_ds());
        filp = filp_open(filename, O_RDONLY, 0);
        if(IS_ERR(filp)) {
            ret = PTR_ERR(filp);
            printk(KERN_INFO "kofile is not opened");
        }
        else
        {
            loff_t offset;
            offset = 0; 
            filesize = filp->f_dentry->d_inode->i_size; 
            if (filesize <= 0 || filesize > 131072)
            {
                goto fileoperror;
            }

            *data = (unsigned char *)vmalloc(filesize);

            if (*data == NULL)
                goto datanull;

            ret = vfs_read(filp, *data, filesize, &offset);

            if(ret != filesize)
                goto read_error; 

            filp_close(filp, NULL);
        }

        set_fs(old_fs);
        return ret;

    fileoperror:
        {
            filp_close(filp, NULL);
            set_fs(old_fs);
            printk(KERN_INFO "Invalid file operation '%s'\n", filename);    
            return (-EPERM); 
        } 
    datanull:
        {
            filp_close(filp, NULL);
            set_fs(old_fs);
            printk(KERN_INFO "Data Buffer is not allocated");
            return (-EFAULT); 
        }

    read_error:
        {
            filp_close(filp, NULL);
            set_fs(old_fs);
            printk(KERN_INFO "Failed to read '%s'.\n", filename);
            return (-EFBIG);    
        }

    }

int read_kofile(const char* filename, unsigned char **data)
{
   return read_file(filename, data);
}
```

HMAC-SHA-512 is calculated on the file by calling Crypto APIs:

```
#define HMAC_SHA512_SIZE 64

struct hmac_sha512_result {
    struct completion completion;
    int err;
};

static void hmac_sha512_complete(struct crypto_async_request *req, int err) {
    struct hmac_sha512_result *r=req->data;
    if(err==-EINPROGRESS)
        return;
    r->err=err;
    complete(&r->completion);
}

int hmac_sha512(const unsigned char *key, // key 
                         const unsigned char *data_in, // data in
                        unsigned char *hash_out, size_t outlen) {  // hash buffer and length

    int rc=0;
    struct crypto_ahash *tfm;
    struct scatterlist sg;
    struct ahash_request *req;
    struct hmac_sha512_result tresult;
    void *hash_buf;
        size_t klen = strlen(key);
        size_t dlen = strlen(data_in); 

        int len = HMAC_SHA512_SIZE;
        char hash_tmp[HMAC_SHA512_SIZE];
    char *hash_res = hash_tmp;

        printk(KERN_INFO "hmac_sha512: HMAC key is %s ", key);

    /* Set hash output to 0 initially */
    memset(hash_out, 0, outlen);

    init_completion(&tresult.completion);
    tfm=crypto_alloc_ahash("hmac(sha512)",0,0);
    if(IS_ERR(tfm)) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "hmac_sha512: crypto_alloc_ahash failed.\n");
        rc=PTR_ERR(tfm);
        goto err_tfm;
    }
    if(!(req=ahash_request_alloc(tfm,GFP_KERNEL))) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "hmac_sha512: failed to allocate request for hmac(sha512)\n");
        rc=-ENOMEM;
        goto err_req;
    }
    if(crypto_ahash_digestsize(tfm)>len) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "hmac_sha512: tfm size > result buffer.\n");
        rc=-EINVAL;
        goto err_req;
    }
    ahash_request_set_callback(req,CRYPTO_TFM_REQ_MAY_BACKLOG,
                    hmac_sha512_complete,&tresult);

    if(!(hash_buf=kzalloc(dlen,GFP_KERNEL))) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "hmac_sha512: failed to kzalloc hash_buf");
        rc=-ENOMEM;
        goto err_hash_buf;
    }
    memcpy(hash_buf,data_in,dlen);
    sg_init_one(&sg,hash_buf,dlen);

    crypto_ahash_clear_flags(tfm,-0);
    if((rc=crypto_ahash_setkey(tfm,key,klen))){
        printk(KERN_ERR "hmac_sha512: crypto_ahash_setkey failed\n");
        goto err_setkey;
    }
    ahash_request_set_crypt(req,&sg,hash_res,dlen);
    rc=crypto_ahash_digest(req);
    switch(rc) {
        case 0:
            while (len--) {
                snprintf(hash_out, outlen, "%02x", (*hash_res++ & 0x0FF));
                hash_out += 2;
            }

                break;
        case -EINPROGRESS:
        case -EBUSY:
            rc=wait_for_completion_interruptible(&tresult.completion);
            if(!rc && !(rc=tresult.err)) {
                INIT_COMPLETION(tresult.completion);
                break;
            } else {
                printk(KERN_ERR "hmac_sha512: wait_for_completion_interruptible failed\n");
                goto out;
            }
        default:
            goto out;
    }

    out:
    err_setkey:
        kfree(hash_buf);
    err_hash_buf:
        ahash_request_free(req);
    err_req:
        crypto_free_ahash(tfm);
    err_tfm:
        return rc;
}
```

Please let me know, if something is missing.

Comment: The kernel's "hmac" is considerably longer than it should be, and there's obviously garbage printed at the end.  Based on this mishandling of binary data, my guess is that you haven't passed the correct arguments to the kernel function.  You're not giving it the base-64-encoded key are you?

Comment: I am passing base64 encoded key to the function.  I am reading the bytes from a file by vfs_read() and passing it to the cryptoapi. Should the. File data be base64 encoded? Is there anything else I am missing.

Comment: Include the code you're using with kernel crypto into your question. Now you just provide the results but not the way how they are obtained (pointed out above too).

Comment: Included the code now.

Comment: Included complete code now. Please have a look.

Comment: Instead of using random keys and data, you should start with test vectors using known parameters and answers. For test vectors, try [RFC 4231, Identifiers and Test Vectors for HMAC-SHA-224, HMAC-SHA-256, HMAC-SHA-384, and HMAC-SHA-512](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4231).

Answer (score 0):

crypto_req_done defined in hash.h

```
 #include <linux/kernel.h>

#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/pci.h>
#include <linux/blkdev.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <linux/dma-mapping.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/dmi.h>
#include <linux/gfp.h>
#include <linux/msi.h>
#include <scsi/scsi_host.h>
#include <scsi/scsi_cmnd.h>
#include <linux/libata.h>
#include <linux/ahci-remap.h>
#include <linux/io-64-nonatomic-lo-hi.h>
#include <net/sock.h>

#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <asm/segment.h>
#include <linux/buffer_head.h>
#include <linux/libata.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <asm/traps.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/kthread.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/sched/signal.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/kthread.h>
#include <linux/hashtable.h>
#include <linux/errno.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/signal_types.h>
#include <linux/fcntl.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/wait.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/crypto.h>

#define MIN(a,b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
#define MAX(a,b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))
#define TESTMGR_POISON_BYTE 0xfe

static int do_ahash_op(int (*op)(struct ahash_request *req), struct ahash_request *req, struct crypto_wait *wait)
{
    int err;
    err = op(req);
    return crypto_wait_req(err, wait);
}
static int check_nonfinal_ahash_op(const char *op, int err){
    if(err < 0){
        pr_err("alg: ahash: %s() failed with err %d on test vector %s\n", op, err, get_error(err));
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

now hmac_sha256:

```
int hmac_sha256(unsigned char *key, size_t key_size, unsigned char *ikm, size_t ikm_len, unsigned char *okm, size_t okm_len){
    int rc, key_is_null;
    struct crypto_ahash *tfm;
    struct ahash_request *req;
    struct scatterlist pending_sgl;
    DECLARE_CRYPTO_WAIT(wait);

    if(key == NULL){
        key = kzalloc(32, GFP_KERNEL);
        key_size = 32;
        key_is_null = 1;
    }else{key_is_null = 0;}
    tfm = crypto_alloc_ahash("hmac(sha256)", 0, 0);
    if(IS_ERR(tfm)) {
        rc=PTR_ERR(tfm);
        printk(KERN_ERR "hmac_sha256: crypto_alloc_ahash failed(%s).\n", get_error(rc));
        goto err_tfm;
    }
    if(!(req = ahash_request_alloc(tfm, GFP_KERNEL))) {
        rc =- ENOMEM;
        printk(KERN_ERR "hmac_sha256: failed to allocate request for hmac(sha512)(%s).\n", get_error(rc));
    }
    if(key_size){
        if((rc = crypto_ahash_setkey(tfm, key, key_size))){
            printk(KERN_ERR "hmac_sha256: crypto_ahash_setkey failed.(%s)\n", get_error(rc));
            goto out;
        }
    }
    sg_init_table(&pending_sgl, 1);
    memset(req->__ctx, TESTMGR_POISON_BYTE, crypto_ahash_reqsize(tfm));
    ahash_request_set_callback(req, CRYPTO_TFM_REQ_MAY_BACKLOG, crypto_req_done, &wait);
    ahash_request_set_crypt(req, NULL, okm, 0);
    rc = do_ahash_op(crypto_ahash_init, req, &wait);
    rc = check_nonfinal_ahash_op("crypto_ahash_init", rc);
    if (rc)
        goto out;

    sg_set_buf(&pending_sgl, ikm, ikm_len);
    ahash_request_set_callback(req, CRYPTO_TFM_REQ_MAY_BACKLOG, crypto_req_done, &wait);
    ahash_request_set_crypt(req, &pending_sgl, okm, okm_len);
    rc = do_ahash_op(crypto_ahash_update, req, &wait);
    rc = check_nonfinal_ahash_op("crypto_ahash_update", rc);
    if(rc)
        goto out;
    rc = do_ahash_op(crypto_ahash_final, req, &wait);
    rc = check_nonfinal_ahash_op("crypto_ahash_final", rc);
    if (rc)
        goto out;
    dump_memory(okm, "hmac_sha256", okm_len);
out:
    ahash_request_free(req);
    crypto_free_ahash(tfm);
err_tfm:
    if(key_is_null)
        kfree(key);
    return rc;
}
```

Break A leg!

```
int hkdf_extract(unsigned char *salt, size_t salt_len, unsigned char *ikm, size_t ikm_len, unsigned char *okm, size_t okm_len){
    return hmac_sha256(salt, salt_len, ikm, ikm_len, okm, okm_len);
}
```